# Array merge between three arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array output:

```
[38] => x._domainkey    14400   IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApYA+ELn4SxsERDFgUB9pUnB4PjbcUlSJoLHAlCq1MLVA3NxgLKSAz+lSczyMH97Y/xOpJf1X1LSoGgNh5GVRn0t"
[39] =>                     "pm1QOPfKbNHx8VMNn4L/KZSPGFyySDUK/UPnF1QoMckoU5a/LgtI8x1ttry5oySDTY9KprVAf92uK6pOFQJA3QlzV2P+R4tx/zho5KlDHmc8YKjL7rLjgQVX7GUBi9cHr0+BQdVFgFL8SwBY8fn/CQ"
[40] =>                     "42JMsEWcMjjEkbAwi9yscGQoTih+kctjr4W8LDF28vyJixozbaFpG8pJ+jGDAho+Zjt/XReOZQP0h51Y8md3/x/F0+gST4mn0mCskNtIQIDAQAB" )
```

How can I get this in de following construction?

```
[38] => x._domainkey    14400   IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApYA+ELn4SxsERDFgUB9pUnB4PjbcUlSJoLHAlCq1MLVA3NxgLKSAz+lSczyMH97Y/xOpJf1X1LSoGgNh5GVRn0tpm1QOPfKbNHx8VMNn4L/KZSPGFyySDUK/UPnF1QoMckoU5a/LgtI8x1ttry5oySDTY9KprVAf92uK6pOFQJA3QlzV2P+R4tx/zho5KlDHmc8YKjL7rLjgQVX7GUBi9cHr0+BQdVFgFL8SwBY8fn/CQ42JMsEWcMjjEkbAwi9yscGQoTih+kctjr4W8LDF28vyJixozbaFpG8pJ+jGDAho+Zjt/XReOZQP0h51Y8md3/x/F0+gST4mn0mCskNtIQIDAQAB" )
```

On one rule.

I tried hard and get the output in multiple array's, but not on one rule:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => x._domainkey 
  [1] => 14400 
  [3] => TXT 
  [4] => ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApYA+ELn4SxsERDFgUB9pUnB4PjbcUlSJoLHAlCq1MLVA3NxgLKSAz+lSczyMH97Y/xOpJf1X1LSoGgNh5GVRn0t" 
) 

Array ( 
  [0] => 
  [1] => 
  [2] => 
  [3] => 
  [4] => 
  [5] => "pm1QOPfKbNHx8VMNn4L/KZSPGFyySDUK/UPnF1QoMckoU5a/LgtI8x1ttry5oySDTY9KprVAf92uK6pOFQJA3QlzV2P+R4tx/zho5KlDHmc8YKjL7rLjgQVX7GUBi9cHr0+BQdVFgFL8SwBY8fn/CQ" 
) 

Array ( 
  [0] => 
  [1] => 
  [2] => 
  [3] => 
  [4] => 
  [5] => "42JMsEWcMjjEkbAwi9yscGQoTih+kctjr4W8LDF28vyJixozbaFpG8pJ+jGDAho+Zjt/XReOZQP0h51Y8md3/x/F0+gST4mn0mCskNtIQIDAQAB" ) 
)
```

I want both array [5] on one rule after [4], is this possible?

Comment: This seems highly specific, can you generalize it? In this exact case you can do this: `echo substr($a[38], 0, -1).trim($a[39], '"').trim($a[40], '"')."\")";`

Comment: The problem is that the lines are different, so when I insert a DNS rule, then the lines can be 42, 43 and 44 next time. So can I use a array search first and then the rules?

Comment: What is the end goal you want to accomplish with this script? Because there are reasons why BIND zone files and TXT records are formatted the way they are, and it is a non trivial operation to interact with them.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the elements after doing some cleanup (removing quotes, parentheses, etc). In this specific case, I removed the last character from the first element (to remove the trailing quote, can be `trim()` or `trim()` too), and used `trim()` to remove leading and trailing quotes on the next two elements.

If the position of these three elements is dynamic, search first by a value that might be unique to your use case (in my example I use `domainkey`) and use that key as the base for the concatenation:

```
<?php
$records = [
2 => "gibberish",
5 => "garbage",
38 => 'x._domainkey    14400   IN  TXT ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEApYA+ELn4SxsERDFgUB9pUnB4PjbcUlSJoLHAlCq1MLVA3NxgLKSAz+lSczyMH97Y/xOpJf1X1LSoGgNh5GVRn0t"',
39 =>                     '"pm1QOPfKbNHx8VMNn4L/KZSPGFyySDUK/UPnF1QoMckoU5a/LgtI8x1ttry5oySDTY9KprVAf92uK6pOFQJA3QlzV2P+R4tx/zho5KlDHmc8YKjL7rLjgQVX7GUBi9cHr0+BQdVFgFL8SwBY8fn/CQ"',
40 =>                     '"42JMsEWcMjjEkbAwi9yscGQoTih+kctjr4W8LDF28vyJixozbaFpG8pJ+jGDAho+Zjt/XReOZQP0h51Y8md3/x/F0+gST4mn0mCskNtIQIDAQAB"'
];
foreach ($records as $i => $record) {
    if (stripos($record, "domainkey") !== false) {
        $initialIndex = $i;
        break;
    }
}
echo substr($records[$initialIndex], 0, -1).trim($records[$initialIndex + 1], '"').trim($records[$initialIndex + 2], '"')."\")";
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gkihu)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't array merging, it's string concatenation.

```
$array[38] .= $array[39] . $array[40]; // combine the 3 lines into one
array_splice($array, 39, 2); // remove the continuation lines
```

You need to do this whenever a line contains `(` before the value. You have to get all the lines until the matching `)` and concatenate them.

Comment: The problem is that the lines are different, so when I insert a DNS rule, then the lines can be 42, 43 and 44 next time. So can I use a array search first and then the rules?

Comment: Loop through the array. When you see an element with `(` in it, concatenate the next element. Keep doing this until you get to the element that ends with `)`.